# On matrices conjugated in a faithful representation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ an algebraically closed field.
Let $O=k[[\pi]]$ and $F=k((\pi))$ and $G\rightarrow GL_{n}$ a faithful representation of a semisimple group.

Let $A, B\in G(O)\cap G(F)^{rs}$ (rs for regular semisimple)) such that there exists $g\in GL_{n}(O)$ such that

$gAg^{-1}=B$,

Does there exist an element $g_{1}\in G(O)$ such that $g_{1}Ag_{1}^{-1}=B$?

Comment: Do any of your conditions prevent $G$ from being a torus?

Comment: Even $SL(2)$ inside $GL(2)$ seem to fail.

Comment: I would prefer the question to be a comparison of the orbits... my naive idea is that more useful things can be said there. definitely the answer to the question in its current form is no. anyway +1.

Comment: it doesn't fail for $SL_{2}$ because if you have $g\in GL_{2}(O)$ that conjugates, then $\frac{1}{\lambda}g\in SL_{2}(O)$ where $\lambda=\sqrt\det(g)$ that exists because $k$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: Ah okay, I wasn't seeing the algebraically closed field part. I was thinking about local fields. Still S.Carnahan's example applies, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't think your edit has fixed much.  For example, $G$ could be $SL_2 \times SL_2$, embedded in $GL_4$, and you could conjugate by something in $GL_4$ that switches the two factors.

Comment: yes but it doesn't imply that the matrices are not conjugated. $g$ and $g_{1}$ are different.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample:  Let $a,b$ be distinct units in $k$ such that $ab \neq 1$, and let $G = SL_2 \times SL_2$ be given the usual block diagonal embedding into $GL_4$.  Then the matrices 
$$A = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} a \\ & 1/a \\ & & b \\ & & & 1/b \end{smallmatrix} \right) \qquad \text{and} \qquad B = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} b \\ & 1/b \\ & & a \\ & & & 1/a \end{smallmatrix} \right)$$ 
are conjugate in $GL_4(O)$, but not $G(O)$.  The underlying problem in this example seems to be that the normalizer of the torus in $G$ is too small.

I suspect Mark Palm's suggestion for $G = SL_2 \hookrightarrow GL_2$ will admit a counterexample when $k$ has characteristic 2, but I have not worked it out.